# Token API and Backend Google OAuth in Node and Angular

Tags: angularjs, express, oauth, google-oauth, passport.js

We are transitioning from an API using cookies for state (ExpressJS sessions) to a stateless (token) API.

We use a single PassportJS authentication strategy (GoogleStrategy). When the OAuth flow completes, Google calls back to a backend route with an access token.

Previously, we would set a cookie at this point using req.session and redirect the user to our dashboard.

With a token API, we generate a token based on the email (acting as a username) and access token (acting as password) when Google calls back to the backend route.

How do we pass this token to the front-end (Angularjs) so that it can make authenticated requests?

Do we need to switch to Google's front-end OAuth APIs?

Answer (score 0):

One way to pass the token to a client-side web application is to put the signed JSON web token into the cookie , which your client-side app can access and use (either appending the token to every GET request or using it in your web socket authentication). Just to be clear, you're no longer using cookies as a reference for server-recorded state, instead you're are simply using them as a storage mechanism that both client and server can access, where you can store your encoded token.

Here's a great example from the *generator-angular-fullstack*:

In the router, receiving the callback from the google authentication:

```
.get('/callback', passport.authenticate('google', {
  failureRedirect: '/signup',
  session: false
 }), auth.setTokenCookie);
```

And the setTokenCookie function:

```
function setTokenCookie(req, res) {
  if (!req.user) return res.json(404, { message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'});
  var token = signToken(req.user._id, req.user.role);
  res.cookie('token', JSON.stringify(token));
  res.redirect('/');
}
```

And the signToken function:

```
function signToken(id) {
  return jwt.sign({ _id: id }, config.secrets.session, { expiresInMinutes: 60*5 });
}
```